# How to send JSON object with special symbols in HTTP Post object

Tags: c#, json, rest, http-post

I am having Json object in below format with symbols like $,£ etc.
When JSON object contains any of these special symbols object is becoming null.

```
 JSON Object:
  {
    "InData": {
        "InDescription": "Q2 2023 - Project  Chart Inv of GBP 44,500,000 in line",
        "InId": "1085",
        "ImpInformation": {
            "Id": "17",
            "Description": "Acqusition in an off-market transaction for £21.7 MM / £4.34MM  to develop logistics warehouse and hold for income.",
            "Name": "Test (Reg)",
            "RegionId": "3"
        }
    },
    "JSONData": {
        "class": "Test",
        ---------------------
        }
    }
```

My object structure is as below:

```
public class Info
{
    public InData IData { get; set; }
    public JSData JSONData { get; set; }
}

 public class InData
{
    public string InDescription { get; set; }
    public string InId { get; set; }
    public ImpData ImpInformation { get; set; }

}

 public class ImpData
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string RegionId { get; set; }
}
```

Here  is my REST Api Post method

```
 [HttpPost]
 [CustomizedExceptionFilters]
 public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SaveData(Info infoData)
 {
 -----
 
 }
```

When I tried to pass above JSON object, it is passing as null to the REST Api method. But when I removed '£' from the description and tried to post, the object is passing with values. Please let me know how can I pass object even if there are special characters anywhere in description

Comment: JSON is encoded in Unicode, preferably UTF-8. So, ensure that the special character is encoded in UTF-8, and you should be good.

Comment: Posting of UTF8-encoded JSON with special characters should work in basically all versions of asp.net.  What I would suggest is to check (and share) the entire raw contents of the post including the headers and the body, maybe there is a problem with the encoding on the client side.